# How to reference another selector in css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using bootstrap in a new project of mine and when I create a table I need to type this code `<table class="table table-responsive table-striped table-bordered table-hover">`

I would like to just use `<table class="table">` and add the rest automatically.

I was hoping this could be done with css like the following:

```
.table {
    add .table-responsive;
    add .table-striped;
    etc...
}
```

Is something like that possible, if not, what should you do to solve this?

Comment: it is not possible in pure css. if you use some css templater language like Sass, you could use @extend for this purpose. however in fact it will just produce css with .table class and copy-pasted css rules of another classes.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with those classes. They all mean something. They allow the person reading the HTML to see what is happening. If you want to combine them, which I don't think is necessary or even advisable, you can use a CSS preprocessor which will provide with something like your `add` (often called `@extend`).

Comment: @TienNguyen please change your comment into a answer. I decieded to use Sass.

Comment: @torazaburo We would like to force our development team to always use the same styling everywhere in the project. Using a lot of classes creates the risk of forgetting one and not having concequent design troughout your application

Comment: Depending on what kind of environment/platform you are using, you should investigate whether you can create a "component" which specifies all the classes in its definition, once, and then you can simply call that component from multiple places in your case. If you are not using an environment/platform which lets you do that, you should consider it IMHO.

Comment: @Tien Nguyen, actually, SASS `@extend` does **not** copy and paste rules, although the effect is sort of like that. Instead, what it does is adds the selector to the list of selectors for the `@extend`-ed class.

Comment: @torazaburo, yes. you are right. actually it will produce .another-class, .table {} rather than .table { __another-class-rules__ }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is not possible in pure css. if you use some css templater language like Sass, you could use @extend for this purpose. however in fact it will just produce css with .table class and copy-pasted css rules of another classes.

--

with @torazaburo remark.
actually it will produce

```
.another-class, .table { another-class-rules }
```

rather than

```
.table { another-class-rules }
```